# Android Studio. Two Apps. One reads, the other writes.

Tags: android

I have an application that can create a list from the user's input. I want to display this list on another app. So basically, the first app can write and even update the list somewhere (not locally on the phone) and the other app can only read the list. What is the simplest way of doing this?

(pls be as descriptive as possible. i'm new to this.)

Comment: Try to post your ideas (which may be off topic) or what you have done to try to accomplish this, or some issues you are facing.

Comment: So basically your idea is: one app write inputs and send to an API (for example), which stores your data. And then another app consume this data from API?

Comment: Yes, Leonardo. Something like that. What would be an easy to use API if you have one in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If do not want to store the list from the first app locally then the other option you have is to store it on server or cloud.

You can try to use firebase database to store that list and make both of your apps share the same database with the first app having read and write permissions and other app only read permission.